# Select st-search not working with ng-model in Angular Smart Table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, smart-table

I am using AngularJS smart table in my application . I am using select to filter my search. Here is my code

```
<select st-search="Status" st-input-event="change" ng-model="filter.Status"  st-delay="false" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Status</option>
    <option value="{{i.Status}}" ng-repeat="i in topicStatus">{{i.Status}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is my AngularJS code:

```
$scope.topicStatus = [
    {
        Id: 1,
        Status: 'Recent'
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Status: 'Most Viewed'
    },
    {
        Id: 3,
        Status: 'Featured'
    },
    {
        Id: 4,
        Status: 'Removed'
    },
    {
        Id: 5,
        Status: 'Featured'
    },
    {
        Id: 6,
        Status: 'Pending'
    }
];
$scope.filter = {};
```

as soon I put `ng-model` in select, my table goes empty . Basically I am saving search filters input by users for future filters, so I want to pick the value of select, but `ng-model` not working.

Need help

Comment: why are you using `st-search` in a select ? what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Updating filter values from controllers

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `st-sort` attribute from inside the table (as it meant to be), like so:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><input st-search="firstName"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

if you want to place a search outside the directive, lets say an outside `<input type="text">` or a `<select ..>` you should write your own directive that handles this.

Luckily for you, you're not the first one who needed this use case. I can refer you to [this](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/220) github issue, and this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kao9707ikzstbvqLFAcc?p=preview) that explains how to filter/search from outside the table.

I took the plunker above and slightly modified it to include a simple select.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/x5TcnzBF7ej2vwsTQCL7?p=preview)

Comment: This is related to whole table search how about different filters for different columns like firstname has its own and so on.

Comment: I don't think searching outside the table in itself is an issue that Smart Table needs or wants to cover. I've seen at least 2 other issues requesting how to do that kind of functionally with the definitive answer being to write your own directive.

Comment: When you update value of <input st-search="firstName"> with javascript table data doesnot get refresh.

Comment: i'm not getting you, when you filter by column your controller data doesn't change, only the data displayed in the view

Comment: Basically I am saving my filter values so when I put filter value from code behind table does not get updated .